# Get _id without ObjectId from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, objectid

I am trying to get the `_id` from a collection without getting the ObjectId part.

When I try and query it this way:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': '$_id'}, 
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': '$_id'
        }
    }
])
```

This returns:

```
ObjectId("51234yhf789")
ObjectId("51234dff779")
ObjectId("51234yhf745")
ObjectId("51234dff123")
ObjectId("51234d45123")
```

Even when I try: `'_id': '$_id'.valueOf()`, I get the same thing.

How do I get:

```
51234yhf789
51234dff779
51234yhf745
51234dff123
51234d45123
```

**Need help for MongoDB V3.6 and below**

Answer (score 4):

On MongoDB version > `4.0` you can use [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/index.html) to convert `ObjectId()` to string :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {'$unwind': '$_id'}, 
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': {$toString : '$_id' }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned this. Its for MongoDB 3.6

Comment: @noob : I don't think you can do that below `4.0`, Also why are you looking for string ? Are you doing anything further with query ? Cause if you just returning from there, then driver in code should automatically convert it to type of string as `ObjectId()` is not of any type related to `JSON`..

Comment: I am trying to join a string with the objectId

Comment: If you would post the query you'd actually like to run, we can help with that directly, see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)